# GRUB installation failed - I see command line instead of menu

Tags: linux, grub, arch-linux

I am just trying to install Arch Linux. To do this, I followed the instructions in the tutorial except for the GRUB installation. This is how the installation looks like according to the tutorial:

```
pacman -S grub-bios os-prober freetype2 ttf-dejavu
os-prober  #I have Windows
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-install /dev/sda
```

The grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg line didn't want to be executed ( I was getting the error that "/boot/grub/grub.cfg" is not such file or directory ) so I skipped it. Then I went on following the tutorial, but when I finally rebooted the computer I found GRUB command line instead of menu.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

you probably forgot to mount the partition first. try again from beginning and exactly follow the Arch Wiki instructions

Comment: I forgot to download microcode